# Tesseract Optimization

Tags: performance, tesseract

I am reading simple timestamps from .png files with tesseract and need to know **what commandline parameters I can use to speed up the process?**

```
time for f in *.png; do tesseract -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789-: -c load_freq_dawg=0 -c load_system_dawg=0 "$f" stdout; done
```

- `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789-:` limits what it can find,
  increasing accuracy in my case
- `-c load_freq_dawg=0 -c load_system_dawg=0` theoretically prevents
  loading of the standard frequency dictionaries but I can't notice
  much of a difference.

I've tried `-c max_permuter_attempts=12` which theoretically limits how many tries tesseract takes on a character (since I'm only letting it find 12..) but speed increase is negligible.

Other parameters are here: http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version

The images all have this form:

[image]

Currently, ten images takes:

```
real    0m1.749s
user    0m1.632s
sys     0m0.096s
```

So, 10,000 will take 30 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

In previous projects i saw that you can specify the "kind" of text that tesseract should expect.

In your case this options might be helpfull :

> -psm NUM              Specify page segmentation mode. NOTE: These
>   options must occur before any configfile.
>
> Page segmentation modes:
>    0    Orientation and script detection (OSD)
>   only.
>   1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
>   2    Automatic
>   page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
>   3    Fully automatic page
>   segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
>   4    Assume a single column of
>   text of variable sizes.
>   5    Assume a single uniform block of
>   vertically aligned text.
>   6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
>   7    Treat the image as a single text line.
>   8    Treat the image as
>   a single word.
>   9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
>   10    Treat the image as a single character.

Try setting -psm 7 for your case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try